# 'rm -rf /' を実行することで何が起こったのか

Tags: macos

コマンドでディレクトリを消す練習をしている際に誤って `rm -rf /` を実行してしまいました。

皆様にご教示頂きたいのは下記２点です。

1. 一体なにが消えてしまったのか（添付画像あり）
2. `operation not permitted` や `Permission denied` と表示されているのは消されずに済んだという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

以下、詳細
当方ruby on railsを勉強の身です。
xcodeやhomebrewを使い環境構築をしておりました。

1. chromeなどアプリや個人的なファイルは残っていたので、
   　なにが消えてしまったかわかりませんでした。

   railsコマンドが通らなかったため、環境構築が吹っ飛んだと思い、
   　xcodeを入れる所から再開しましたがxcodeは消えていなかったようで、
   　homebrewを入れるところから再開しました。

   現状、復旧作業中です。
   　ルートディレクトリの構成について調べたのですが
   　何が消えてしまったのか検討がつかなかったため
   　質問させて頂きました。
   　どこに何を保存しているかなどは個人によりけりで回答が難しいかと存じますが、
   　「ユーザーが個人的に入れたアプリが消えてしまったよ」のようにザックリで構いませんので
   　ご教示いただければ幸いです。
2. 上から20行程度は放心状態で「control + c」をすぐに入力できず、
   　operation not permitedと高速で表示されているなかcontrol+cを実行しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 画像の前半は `ls` でファイルの一覧を表示した結果のようにも見えますが、本当に `rm` 実行時の表示でしょうか？ (二度実行したということ？)

Answer (score 2):

macOS固有の挙動については詳しくありませんが、一般的なLinuxでの話をすると、

- `rm` コマンド実行時にオプションで `-i` や `-v` を指定すれば削除時にファイル名が表示されますが、実際の削除が行われた後にどのファイルが削除されたかを**確認することはできません。**
  (ですので、コマンドでの操作は慎重に行う必要があります)
- `/` 直下にあるディレクトリ群を操作(=削除を含む編集)するには基本的に管理者(root)権限が必要です。
  `rm` コマンドを管理者権限で実行していない限り、ユーザー権限で削除してしまった可能性があるのは `/home/<USER>` 以下の個人ファイルや、`/tmp/` 以下に作成したファイルじゃないかと思われます。
  これら以外は `Permission denied` などのエラーが出ている通り、権限で弾かれて削除されずに残っているはずです。
- "簡単なサンプル環境 = 単一ディレクトリの下に複数ファイルを置いただけ" で試した限り、複数のファイルが操作対象となる場合はおおよそファイル名の辞書順(a-z)に処理されているように見えます。
  ただし階層が深いリストを処理する場合にどうなるかまでは確証がありません。

Answer (score 1):

> 一体なにが消えてしまったのか（添付画像あり）

実行したユーザ に 書き込み権限のあるすべての ファイル と ディレクトリが削除されたと思います。ただ、ディレクトリ内にファイルが残っていれば、そのディレクトリは削除されてません。

> operation not permitted や Permission denied と表示されているのは消されずに済んだという認識でよろしいでしょうか？

そうです。